# Get current item details on button click Android

Tags: android

```
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                View v, int position, long id) {
            b.setTag(position);
            City city = (City) a.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("in.wptrafficanalyzer.listviewcheckbox.City", city);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    int position = (Integer)arg0.getTag();
                    String name = mListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
              }
            });
```

This is what I have done so far regarding the items list/item details. The list works just fine and the details are shown when I click on a specific item.

I want to get the details from the TextView of the currently selected item.

For example let's say I have the list item `Carrot`. I click on it and the item's details are displayed saying: `Carrots have vitamin A` . How do I get that string and assign it to a String variable?

I have tried getting the position and then getting the item to that position. I haven't tried to get the details of that item because it gives me an error.

I am working in Android Studio and whatever error I get it prints the same stack? The only thing that allows me to determine where the error lays is the fact that it specifies the line.

Thanks..

Edit: Stack Trace

```
04-20 00:30:19.335  12519-12519/in.wptrafficanalyzer.listviewcheckbox E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-20 00:30:19.495  12519-12519/in.wptrafficanalyzer.listviewcheckbox W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f6e390)
 04-20 00:30:19.505  12519-12519/in.wptrafficanalyzer.listviewcheckbox E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main

 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.listviewcheckbox/in.wptrafficanalyzer.listviewcheckbox.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at in.wptrafficanalyzer.listviewcheckbox.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Attention: I am not trying to get the current selected item, but the item's details, as the button `b` is inside the item details layout.

Comment: You mention you are getting a stack trace. Please include it in your question.

Comment: I did. But I get the same stack trace for any error for some reason..

Comment: wouldn't it be eaiser if you defined an int variable in your activity instead of making your life a missilery with tags? :/

Comment: @BojanKseneman I tried that too. Didn't work :(

Comment: the b button is outside the listview?

Comment: @BojanKseneman the b button is inside the details layout.

Comment: Are the two click listeners in your code in different Activities?  Can you clarify exactly what file each section of code is in?

Comment: @DanielNugent The code is from the same file. Both listeners. But the viewlist is from one layout and the button is from another. Could that represent any problem? What if I have used a master/detail layout provided by Studio? How could I have got the details of an item?

Answer (score 0):

inside your `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id)` you might get value for position using `mListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);`. also `View v` is your whole list row you've clicked, so if you want only text from it you might use smth like:

```
String yourText = 
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewInRow)).getText().toString();
```

if you are using some kind of default adapter (e.g. `ArrayAdapter`) default id may be `android.R.id.text1` or `android.R.id.text` (depends on deafult view for adapter and count of views in each row)